# How to use IdentityServerClientCorsOrigins? (ABP.IO)

Tags: identityserver4, abp

Currently the cors origins are configured in the appsettings however I am not able to configure in way that it gets the origins from the SQL Server database.

[image]

I have commented out that withOrigins sections however I have it already configured in the database but it gets rejected

[image]

This is the error I get when I am calling from http://localhost:3000

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ids.local/connect/userinfo' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply these on IdentityServer project:

1. Add `AllowedCorsOrigins` to the client's configuration on `Config.cs` or in DB (if using EF)

```
AllowedCorsOrigins =
                        { 
                            "http://localhost:3000" 
                        },
```

Be sure to use an origin (not a URL) when configuring CORS. For example: https://foo:123/ is a URL, whereas https://foo:123 is an origin.

Ref: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/cors.html#client-based-cors-configuration

2. In case you have custom cors policy, add it on `startup.cs` - `ConfigureServices`.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

3. On `startup.cs` - `Configure`, add cors after IdentityServer.

```
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseCors("default");
```

IDS4 already register a custom cors policy, if you have one too make sure to add it after IDS4 middleware

Comment: thanks for the answer however I want to get the CorsOrigins from SQL Server Database.  I do not want to hard code it, not have it in the appsettings.json

Comment: Whats the value you have on DB?

Comment: Updated my answer I guess i know ur issue, its cause of ordering of middleware

Comment: It's confusing. I only want the setup and the config if we are using SQL server database using EF. Again I am not using custom CORS so any config I want to be retrieve from IdentityServer4 database tables

Comment: Do you still have that default policy in ur code? The one you posted snapshot or not? 
If yes you need to add it after IDS4 to avoid conflict

Comment: I removed the default policy. ie context.services.AddCors(...etc as I want the configuration to be retrieved by IDS4 from SQL Server. does that make sense? so all I left with is app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseCors(); ... is that correct?

Comment: You dont need the usecors as well, just remove that too, here is a working example https://github.com/nahidf/IdentityServer4-adventures/blob/ndc-sydney-2020/src/IdentityServer/Startup.cs. I have a JS client in my sample which is fully functional just by having cors setting on client config(my sample is in memory but no different for db)